why when spring boot starts, Jarsigner is not triggered?
I use the Jarsigner Maven Plugin as Follows.
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>sign</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sign</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <keystore>${project.basedir}/JarKeyStore.jks</keystore>
                <alias>myalias</alias>
                <storepass>P@ssw0rd</storepass>
                <keypass>P@ssw0rd</keypass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

and i generate the JarKetStore.jks file.
After I packaged the package, I could indeed see the files generated in the jar package.

But when I tried to replace the class file inside and then start the spring boot project, Jarsigner did not prevent me from starting it and it became normal.My Jarsigner is not working?
However, when I try to replace a class file in the sub-package of this spring boot project (also verified by Jarsigner), an error will be reported when starting.


Yes, I've never understood when, if ever, signed JARs get checked. You would have thought the JVM would do it, but in my experience it doesn't.
